# How to add margins between twitter bootstrap columns without causing the grid to break?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Twitter Bootstrap v3.0.3. My question relates to the attached screenshot.How can I add margins between the columns without causing the third column to drop/wrap[image: screenshot of layout][image: screenshot of code]

Comment: Do you want equal heights or what do you want. The first answer is correct if you don't care about equal heights. You'd put a div directly inside, wrapping the col- and stick the background on that, if you want equal heights that's another thing.

Comment: Equal heights not a requirement in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This effect could be achieved by using the `padding` declaration.

However this requires that an inner element defines the background color.

This will not cause the columns to expand as Bootstrap 3 uses `box-sizing` on its columns.

**Edit:**

Also, note that [only columns should be immediate children of rows](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)(List item 3).

Comment: Thanks for alerting me to the fact that columns have to be immediate children of rows